# xaml binding Listview element to another datasource (WinRT)

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a viewModel which consists of a class and an Observable collection

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public string SomeName {set; get;};
    public ObservableCollection<ItemName> ItemNames {set; get;}
}
```

In the Page i am setting the DataContext of the page itself to this object i.e.

```
MyViewModel myModel = new MyViewModel("111");
this.DataContext = myModel;
```

Then i have a ListView in the page design which references to the datacontext, and i can get the value from it using the ItemSource property

```
<ListView
....
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemNames}">
```

However, within this ListView, **how do i access the "SomeName" Property?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using WinRT, and the way I found it to work was by setting the source to 'Binding' and then give the Path to the Object

```
Text="{Binding Source={Binding}, Path=SomeName}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView` needs definition for columns. Each column can be bound to a different property.

In your case:

```
<ListView 
....
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemNames}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="The Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SomeName}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: That explains it for xaml, however GridViewColumn is not accessible for winRT, and the way i solved it was to set the Text property to 'Text="{Binding Source={Binding}, Path=SomeName}"'